# Does addView() invoke onMeasure() for all childs?

Tags: android, view, viewgroup

does adding a child to a ViewGroup (via ViewGroup.addView() ) automatically invoke onMeasure() for all childs?

Comment: Could you not try it by doing some logging or by using break points?

Answer (score 2):

`ViewGroup` should measure it's width and height by first measuring all children. If `ViewGroup`'s width or height is wrap_content it will call `onMeasure()` for all children for sure. Can't say that about match_parent. One thing for sure that `addView()` calls `requestLayout()` which will re-calculate layout children's position call `layout(l, t, r, b)` on all children.

To know for sure if it calls you can create a custom `View` and log every call to `onMeasure()` and add those to a `ViewGroup`. Could be that different `ViewGroup` implementation will act differently.